# Cakephp: Update  records without refering the primary key

Tags: php, cakephp

I am trying to update number of records  with respect to their thread Id. Here is a problem my **id_thread** field is not a primary key . But as far as  I know cakephp only  supporting updating content relating with  primary id .

**Used code**

```
$this->contact->id_thread = $id;        
$this->Contact->saveField('is_read','y');
```

But this is not worked for me. Any ideas ?

**My DB structure**

```
id   |id_thread |  id_sender| is_read | status
_______________________________________________
1    | 2        |   2       | n       | 1
2    | 2        |   1       | n       | 1
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

saveField is only intended to work on the currently loaded record.  To update multiple records of the same model, use `updateAll`.

Usage:

> **Model::updateAll(array $fields, array $conditions)**
>
> Updates many records in a single call. Records to be updated are identified by the $conditions array, and fields to be updated, along with their values, are identified by the $fields array.
>
> [source](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-updateall-array-fields-array-conditions)

In your case, it would look like this:

```
$this->Contact->updateAll(
    array( 'Contact.is_read' => 'y' ),   //fields to update
    array( 'Contact.id_thread' => $id )  //condition
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `id_thred` field doesn't seems to be unique. So even if you make a SQL query to update the data, it will update the two rows. is this what yo are expecting?

My suggestion would be call a find method with condition `id_thread` and get the primary key id and update the value using `saveField` method

Comment: No , Exactly I want that, Update multiple rows